# Did Dishes with Radiator Water For a Year

Tags: water, heating, water-heater, hot-water, radiator

The valves connected between my (serpentine) hot water tank and radiators is broken. Moreover the serpentine is broken and hence the hot water for showering and doing the dishes has been cross-contaminated with the water for the radiators. The water smells and I’m changing the tank and valve. What could be the potential contaminants in this water?

PS: I think there’s magnetite in it, but I don’t know what else there could be. Do you?

Comment: Did you wipe the dishes dry?  Most health hazards would from drinking/ingesting the water.

Comment: The dishwasher allowed the dishes to dry out, but I can’t know if the toxic bits clung on to the dishes

Comment: You know if any chemicals where added to the radiator system?  They probably what to worry a bit about, usually if you don't taste them, then concentration is low enough.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be pulling whatever documentation you keep on your boiler to see if there's been any chemical treatments run on its water system for the past while

Comment: How have you been feeling lately?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about medical conditions, not home improvement.

Comment: That ship has sailed. But once you fix it you'll only be better off.

Answer (score 1):

Based on advice I have heard in the past regarding lead, which is a major health hazard in many places, if you let water run so that the water you are using is "fresh" from the municipal supply then you significantly mitigate health effects from your own pipes - or in this case, radiators, valves, boiler, etc.). The water that sits in the pipes for a long time is much more likely to absorb chemicals from the pipes than water that is just passing through very quickly.

Certainly the bigger hazard is for drinking water than for washing dishes, though even with dishes there can be some residual effect. Bottom line: If your dishwashing process was "fill sink with hot water that turned out be suboptimal", "soak", "rinse", then you have may have *some* effect. If your dishwashing process is "constantly running water to soap the dishes, wash and rinse" then there is much less of an effect - to the extent that I generally wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Given the fact that his valves is broken and the both circuits have mixed up, i doubt, that there will be fresh water even after running the tap for a long time...